# Transaction log for temp db is full. How not to use a log?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logging, server, ssms

I have a rather heavy `DELETE` operation that tries to delete rows in a temp table which do not have a match in another database table.

```
DELETE FROM ##SendRecipients
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT RecipientId FROM MyDB.dbo.Results)
```

After about 10 minutes, I get the follwoing error message:

> The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to
>   'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

My attempts at adding a new log file for tempdb was to no avail. And now the database files together with the `.ldf` files of the log (spread across three drives), have clogged the server space.

Is there a way to tell tempdb not to use a log, at least only for this operation? It seems like one cannot modify much in tempdb.

Does moving the temp tables inside the databases help as an alternative?

Comment: If you're populating a temporary table, why not ensure the correct data goes in first my adding a `NOT EXISTS` clause to the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Short answer: NO. You can't **not** use log in SQLServer (and most of the RDBMS-es too). As for prolonged answer: it's a case when specific version **and** edition of SQLServer is crucial

Comment: @Larnu you have a point. let me try!

Comment: I would look for: a) `DBCC OPENTRAN` - look for open transactions, maybe there are culprits, b) check if [it's not a case](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2963384/fix-sql-server-crashes-when-the-log-file-of-tempdb-database-is-full-in), c) "moving the temp tables inside the databases" - certainly could solve the problem but another problems could arise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you probably don't want to use a global temp table.  Their utility is very limited.

To reduce the logging, you could do this:

```
select *
into #SendRecipients2
from #SendRecipients
WHERE Id IN (SELECT RecipientId FROM MyDB.dbo.Results)
```

Which should be minimally-logged, or if you aren't in an explicit transaction

```
while 1=1
begin
   DELETE top (10000) FROM #SendRecipients
   WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT RecipientId FROM MyDB.dbo.Results)
   if @@rowcount = 0 break;
end
```

which will allow the transaction log space to be reused for each statement.

Another option is to use a table variable instead of a temp table.  Modifications to table variables are never logged.

Comment: I will try both your solutions and come back to you. Does using global temp tables cause trouble?

Comment: Yes.  If you run two instances of your stored procedure, or any other stored procedure that uses the same global temp table names, they will interfere with each other.